# how to add an event in angular 4 to a html added with external library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I'm using the jQuery wizard library and it adds the next and back buttons from its code. (https://github.com/thecreation/jquery-wizard).

I need to execute a method when the next button is clicked. (The button that is added from the library).
I have this code but doesn't work.

```
    import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-wizard',
        templateUrl: './app-wizard.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./app-wizard.component.css']
    })
    export class WizardComponent implements OnInit {


        constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
        }

        ngOnInit() {
        }

        ngAfterViewInit(){
            var el = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#next-button');
            let elem:Element = document.getElementById("next-button");
            //retun null
            console.log(document.getElementById("next-button"));
            //return null
            console.log(el);
            //return null
            console.log(elem);
        }

        ngAfterViewChecked(){
            var el = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#next-button');
            let elem:Element = document.getElementById("next-button");
            //retun null
            console.log(document.getElementById("next-button"));
            //return null
            console.log(el);
            //return null
            console.log(elem);
        }
    }
```

The id next-button I added to jquery-wizard.js is the line 96.
This is the change.

```
templates: {
            buttons: function() {
                var options = this.options;
                return '<div class="wizard-buttons">' +
                    '<a id="back-button" (click)="checkCurrentTab()" class="wizard-back" href="#' + this.id + '" data-wizard="back" role="button">' + options.buttonLabels.back + '</a>' +
                    '<a  id="next-button" (click)="checkCurrentTab()" class="wizard-next" href="#' + this.id + '" data-wizard="next" role="button">' + options.buttonLabels.next + '</a>' +
                    '<a class="wizard-finish"  href="#' + this.id + '" data-wizard="finish" role="button">' + options.buttonLabels.finish + '</a>' +
                    '</div>';
            }
        },
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use **ng-click** like this:

```
<a id="back-button" ng-click=checkCurrentTab()" class="wizard-back" href="#' + this.id + '" data-wizard="back" role="button"> ...</a>
```